# How to set previous state on useState using Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the current state:
`const [newInvoice, setInvoice] = useState<InvoiceType | null>(invoice)`

My type for `InvoiceType` is :

```
  customer_email: string
  customer_name: string
  description: string
  due_date: string
  status: FilterButtonState
  total: number
  line_items: LineItemType[]
```

I am trying to modify state in my form to modify previous state using an input field like follows:

```
<input
   ...otherAttributes
   onChange={(ev: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void =>
   setInvoice((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
       customer_name: ev.target.value
    }))
/>
```

But I keep getting the following Type error: `Argument of type '(prevState: InvoiceType | null) => { customer_name: string; customer_email?: string | undefined; description?: string | undefined; due_date?: string | undefined; status?: FilterButtonState | undefined; total?: number | undefined; line_items?: LineItemType[] | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<InvoiceType | null>'`

I am not sure how to structure this so that I can get around this issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Nit-picking: `InvoiceType` is redundant -> `Invoice`.

Answer (score 3):

You defined the state as `InvoiceType | null`, so `prevState` can be `null`. You must add a guard before using it:

```
prevState => prevState ? { ...prevState, customer_name: ev.target.value } : null
```

The another approach is to define the state so it always has a value: `useState(invoice || emptyInvoice)`. And then you can keep your code for the update.

Comment: YES. Thank you!

Comment: So this solution allows me to add the form values if prevState exists, but what if its a new form and current state is `null`?

Comment: Then you'd write `prevState => ({... emptyInvoice, customer_name: ev.target.value})`. Or probably better, initialize the state so it always has a value: `useState(invoice || emptyInvoice)`.